# Selective replacements

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

I would like to replace parts of the expression, with variables `p[1]` and `p[2]`, that are invariant under inversion `p[1] <-> p[2]`. Namely I would like to replace `p[1] * p[2]` as `pro`, and `p[1] + p[2]` as `sum`.

```
exp = x /. Solve[{
       x == 2 p[1] p[2] + p[1] q[2] (2 + x) + q[1] (1 + y),
       y == 2 p[1] p[2] + q[1] p[2] (2 + y) + q[2] (1 + x)},
      {x, y}][[1]] /. q[i_] :> 1 - p[i] // Simplify
```

This is nearly there, but for this expression specifically. Although I think my goal is posed loosely, my question is: how would I go about this in a convenient way?

```
MapAt[ExpandAll
  , exp, {2}] //. {p[1]^a_.*p[2]^a_. :> pro^a, b_.*p[1] + b_.*p[2] :> b*sum}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `p[1]^2 p[2]` be `p[1] pro`?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, hence *nearly*. Ok, I see I can replace general pattern `p[1]^a_.*p[2]^b_.` correctly. Can I do without prior `ExpandAll` selective mapping?

Comment: `Eliminate[ {exp == 0, pro == p[1] p[2], sum == p[1] + p[2]}, {p[1], p[2]}]`

Comment: @Kuba No, not what I would like to have. The expression is not totally invariant, I'd like to replace just the invariant parts and see what is left that is not invariant ... I can do it by hand quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Simplify`/`FullSimplify` with `ComplexityFunction` to indicate the correctness of the output.

```
t1[e_] := ReplacePart[e, RandomChoice[Position[e, p[1]]] -> pro/p[2]]
t2[e_] := ReplacePart[e, RandomChoice[Position[e, p[2]]] -> pro/p[1]]
t3[e_] := ReplacePart[e, RandomChoice[Position[e, p[1]]] -> sum - p[2]]
t4[e_] := ReplacePart[e, RandomChoice[Position[e, p[2]]] -> sum - p[1]]

FullSimplify[exp, TransformationFunctions -> {t1, t2, t3, t4, Automatic},
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + Length[Position[#, p[1] | p[2]]] &)]
```

> $\frac{(p(1)-1) \text{pro}+2}{\text{pro} (\text{pro}-\text{sum}+2)}$

Maybe multiply the second term of the complexity function by more than 1.

Comment: This is sort of amazing. Also works: `-> RandomChoice[{pro/p[2], sum - p[2]}]]`, halving the number of t's.